# Error Installing Postsharp in Visual Studio 2015 -532462766

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, postsharp

I've just setup a new development PC with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015.

When I try to install the Postsharp extension the installer gets to the "Configuring Visual Studio" step and throws the error:

> Could not start VsixInstaller.exe: The VISX installer processs failed with exit code -532462766

I saw on another post this could be because of an older version of Nuget, but I'm currently upto date on 3.1.60724.766

Comment: What PostSharp and Visual Studio version do you use (RTM, RC)? PostSharp installer produces installation log in %localappdata%\temp. Please, could you report this to PostSharp support and attach all VSIXInstaller*.log files from %localappdata%\temp?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 RTM (14.0.23107.0 D14REL) and trying to install Postsharp version 4.1.23. I'll report it to Postsharp support now

Comment: This discussion is continuing here http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2841-error-installing-postsharp-in-visual-studio-2015-532462766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by running the postsharp exe with administrator privileges (right click "run as administrator).

In the Windows Application Events I found an error:

> VsixInstaller.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException

This looks like a known issue https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/28. It looks some confusion between Win 10 UAC and the VISX installer.

I my case my UAC setting was second from the top "Notify me when applications try to make changes to my computer"